# Auto scrolling in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to achieve auto scrolling with circular scrolling in AngularJS. There is a [jQuery plugin](http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/scrollable/plugins.html#autoscroll) which does exactly what I want.

Is there a way to achieve this using AngularJS (since many advise not to use jQuery with AngularJS)?

Comment: Are you looking for [`ui-carousel`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) plugin?

Comment: Well its pretty close. My requirement is there will be about 5 records in the visible area. And there can be 50 total records and we should be able to auto scroll through the 50 records recursively. So there should be 5 in the visible area at a time.